# create a list of integers from a to b in python

Tags: python-3.x

Create a list of integers from from a (inclusive) to b (inclusive).
Example:
`integers(2,5)` returns `[2, 3, 4, 5]`.

I know this is probably an easy one, but I just can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> def integers(a, b):
         return list(range(a, b+1))
>>> integers(2, 5)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To explain your own solution:

> can you explain to me why in some programs you have to include `[i]` and some it is just `i`
>
> ```
> def integers(a,b):
>    list = []
>    for i in range(a, b+1):
>        list = list + [i]
> ```

`i` refers to the number itself; `[i]` is a list with one element, `i`. When using the `+` operator for lists, Python can concat two lists, so `[1, 2] + [3, 4]` is `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. It is however not possible to just add a single element (or number in this case) to an existing list. Trying so will result in a `TypeError`.

What you could do instead of concatenating with a one-element list, is simply append the element by using the method with the same name:

```
list.append(i)
```

One final note, you should not name your variable `list` (or `dict` or `str` etc) as that will locally overwrite the references to the built-in functions/types.

Answer (score 3):

A [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) makes the most sense here.  It's terse and doesn't involve appending unnecessarily to the list (on your end).

```
def integers(a, b):
    return [i for i in range(a, b+1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

use np.arange.  Example

```
    i=np.arange(1,9)
```

This will result in

```
    array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8])
```

Arrays are nicer than lists in python

Comment: @steveha I am putting the answer to your question here:  list(range(9)).  Easier than doing numpy.arange(9).tolist().

Answer (score 0):

This question is very easy; I don't want to just tell you the answer because you can look it up.  Look at the documentation for the built-in function `range()`.  Since you are using Python 3.x, you will need to explicitly force the output of `range()` to expand out to a list by wrapping it with a call to `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

Very compact, and using Python standard library only:

```
i=range(6)[2:]
```

Creates a list with 6 members from 0 to 6, and selects the members with indices 2 to the end.

```
print(i)
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To select a different range, try:

```
i=range(6)[2:4]

print(i)
[2, 3]
```