# Python 3.4 i want creat list 0,24,48,.......6168

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to have result like this in python 3.4 moving by 24

```
0
24
48
72
.
.
.
6186
```

Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cahLT.jpg

Comment: Yes, see the `range()` function.

Comment: for n in range(0,100,24): print(n)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849618/create-a-list-of-integers-from-a-to-b-in-python check this out, I am sure it will help you.

Comment: Thanks all and especially @zetysz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will have to overload the range function

```
for i in range(0,n,24):
    print(i)


Output:
0
24
48
72...
```